# How can I get the name of the arguments a vscode command receives?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, visual-studio-code

For instance, `git.clone` is the id of the vscode command that clones a project from a url. In the vscode official website, (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) there are only *some* commands mentioned, but not **all** of them. Where are all commands documented? Currently, I have to get the id of all commands by executing in the command palette this command: `Preferences: Open Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`. It just doesn't make sense to have to go through the keyboard bindings to get the id of the commands, right?

Is there also another way to get an exhaustive list of all command ids?

Comment: Such a list doesn't exist.